# Don't see database in Robot3T connecting to Atlas

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas, robo3t

I'm connection to Atlas Replica Set using Robo3T. On Advanced tab I set Default Database to MongoLab. So I expect on connection to see it in the tree view on the left side. But the only thing I see is Replica Set collection and System with admin database. Am I doing something wrong here? Where can I find visual list of collections in database?
[image]

[image]

PS: Please do not recommend me to use Compass, I already checked it and it's horrible :(

Comment: What does `On Advanced tab I set Default Database to MongoLab` mean? if it's a connection setting in Robo3T, connecting to Mongo won't create an empty database for you.

Comment: I already have that database. `use MongoLab` returns correct result `switched to db MongoLab`.

Comment: Why don't you try Studio 3T :). Anyways, two things come to my mind. First, you may connected to non-primary server which somehow end up not showing the database name you want. Or maybe you do not have roles/rights to list those databases?

Comment: Because it's $150 per year and I'm not DBA to pay that much for it :) You are right, I can't execute `db.adminCommand( { listDatabases: 1 } )` with error `not authorized on admin to execute command` but I don't follow how to fix that :(